# Does MySQL retain unique IDs between connections

Tags: mysql, database, create-table

I would like to know if MySQL retains unique IDs it has automatically assigned between connections.
I copied the creation script of a table from the test environment to the production environment, and when testing if it works correctly, noticed that a new record was inserted into this table (production) using the next ID after that of the last record inserted into the same table in the test environment. Is this normal behavior? It's not an issue, as much as it is peculiar.

Here is the creation script below:

```
CREATE TABLE `audit_logs` (
  `log_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `log_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `workflow_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `workflow_step` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `workflow_step_status` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `step_modified_by` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `area` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fixture` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`),
  KEY `workflow_id` (`workflow_id`),
  KEY `FK_ItemAuditLog` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ItemAuditLog` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `items` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `audit_logs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`workflow_id`) REFERENCES `workflows` (`workflow_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=192 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Well, show the script. It might contain code that touches auto-increment sequences.

Comment: Edited. Thanks Sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure your problems comes from this line;

```
AUTO_INCREMENT=192
```

Which results in that the unique ID will start at 192 on the first insert in the table on the new server.

Comment: I clearly still have much to learn about MySQL (coming from a SQL Server background) - thank you for this answer! And thank you to Sergio too